# How to handle images folder with many images

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, image

I'm developing a new aspnet website with 200k images in a /Images/ -folder.

Many operations in Visual Studio is slow because it access the folder, adding a web service takes 10 minutes.

The images is not checked into scm (svn).

How should I structure the tree of code, to improve performance in VS?

It would also be neat if not all developers needed to copy 200k images to their local disk to be able to develop on the site.

Images as DB blobs is not an option.

Comment: This is 200KB not 200MB? 10 minutes to add a web service sounds more like a connection issue rather then a 200KB worth of images issue. The fact you state the images are local (debating to copy them local for other dev) is reason enough that VS should not be choking on 200KB of data.

Comment: I think he means what he says.. He have 200,000 images in the folder

Comment: 200000 images. I don't think their size matters (~3gb), it's the count that VS chokes on.

Comment: Misunderstood...thanks for clarity...

Answer (score 1):

Put the image-directory outside the project and if your images at least have corresponding entries in db, use ID to create subdirs.

Rule of thumb, direcory shouldn't contain more than 10k files.

```
path = [id / 10^6] / [ id / 10^3] / [ id]
```

regards
/t

Answer (score 1):

Use a Shared folder on the network, and point to that location, set the App-pool identity property if you run under iis.

Comment: How can images from a shared folder on the network be included in the local site's tree when accessing the site with http?

Comment: @Billy - Once you place the files outside your website's visual studio directory, you want to setup a 'virtual directory' to that network path inside IIS with the name 'images'.   I am assuming you are using IIS.   Let me know if you are not.

Comment: IIS for production, but Cassini (VS development web server) for development.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to manage this, you could simply "Exclude from Project" the folder with images in it.

However, keep in mind that using the "Publish" option of Visual Studio the images would not be there.

Comment: The most up-to-date images, "content", is already at the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the images from the VS solution but include them in SVN.
The developers can chose to not checkout the images from SVN should they not need them.
VS will still find the images when running but you just lose intelisense on them.

Comment: Most of the images is site-user created content, should not go into svn. Graphics like menus and logos should of course.

Answer (score 0):

### Performance Considerations

---

#### Use Multiple Folders

- Having a single folder with 200,000 image files in it is not a good idea.  You should see if you can break them into multiple folders such as A,B,C,D.

#### Use A Temporary Working Folder

- Create a temporary working folder where anything and everything you want to do with the image is performed.

  - Move files from the working folder to their storage location (i.e. A,B,C,D)

#### No Reading Filenames

- Do not attempt to read the filenames from disc.  Doing so will result in terrible performance.

  - Instead you should store the filename and path to your images instead.
  - You can work with this in memory instead and you will have great performance.